# Using factors in R programming

Tags: r

If I have the code:

```
x <- c(rnorm(10),runif(10), rnorm(10,1))

f <- gl(3,10)

f 

[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
Levels: 1 2 3

tapply(x,f,mean)

    1           2            3

0.07368817  0.42992416  0.64212383
```

How are the 1,2,3's decided? I am assuming they are levels of something.

Furthermore, why is f used in the second argument, I dont see why it is an index and how does it know when to stop running through the index?.

I tried looking up the function definition but to no avail.

Comment: you can get the functions' source by typing `tapply` and pressing enter.

Comment: Using `gl` you've set your factor levels to be `1 2 3`, so all `tapply` did is separating the `x` into 3 groups according to the indexes and their levels and compute `mean` for each group, that's all

Comment: The 1,2,3 were generated by `gl`... what do you mean by "how are they decided"?

Comment: you can specify labels to be used, e.g. try `gl(3,10, labels = LETTERS[1:3])` and read about it by typing `?gl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about how `tapply` works (rather than `gl`) consider another simpler example:

```
   > x1 <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
   > tapply(x1, x1, mean)
   1 2 3 
   1 2 3

   > f2 <- c(2,2,2,2,3,3)
   > tapply(x1, f2, mean)
     2   3 
   1.5 3.0
```

In the first case, `tapply` has picked the first two items (indices), and found their mean
giving 1 for 1, then the next two items (2 and 2) having mean 2 etc.

In the second case, the first 4 items are treated as 2's, having mean (1+1+2+2)/4, and the last two and 3's having mean (3+3)/2

In effect, then "index" is labelling the data, and applying the requested function to each "group"